# How to get location when app goes to background or phone is locked?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying using `locationManager` to get my location and update it to my webservice.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    //some code here
}
```

It's normal, but if my app goes to the background or phone screen is locked, updating location may be paused. How do I get the location anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Read the full blog post on it: [iPhone Background GPS: accurate to 500m, not enough for foot traffic](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/07/22/iphone-background-gps-accurate-to-500-meters-not-enough-for-foot-traffic/#more-480)

Here is a tutorial: [iOS Multitasking: Background Location](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you set up a handler such as this example:

[TTLocationHandler](https://github.com/dsdavids/TTLocationHandler)

Configure the handler for the recency and accuracy required. Set up a listener for the notification "LocationHandlerDidUpdateLocation". Put your code to upload the data in a method called on receipt of that notification.

If you do not require fine grain detail, I would advise you use the battery saving options of significantLocationChange monitoring in background. In that case you will not need to add background mode in info.plist and you will not waste resources unnecessarily. The app will be awakened and your method called only on significant movement of the user. There is configurable options in the handler to require constant monitoring in background and/or foreground, and to set recency and accuracy thresholds.

See the LMPinTracker class for example of how to respond and save your data to web or locally. See the thread [Invoke get current coordinates every few seconds without NSTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841017/invoke-get-current-coordinates-every-few-seconds-without-nstimer/12842463#12842463) for discussion of use.

Comment: Does it works when the device is locked? As far as I have seen startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges doesn't work when the device is locked. It works perfectly well in background when user is using other apps ( i.e., when device is not sleeping)

Comment: The significant location change event will wake the app when locked, but none of your delegate methods will fire in the background unless you wrap them in a UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier assignment. That gives your method a limited amount of time to process the event and will kill your app if you do not handle the expiration by canceling all work in progress and ending the task.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am creating a background task in didUpdateLocations but if the delegate method will not be called before creating background task then how can I create the background task?

Comment: Wherever you are responding to the location manager location update, start by assigning a UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier. Be sure to end the task with endBackgroundTaskIdentifier: when finished and be sure to end the task in an expiration handler for the case that the system decides to cut your time short prior to reaching the end of your task. If you call other methods from that task, as long as they are synchronous, this will work. If you call an asynchronous process, it will need its own identifier and expiration handler.

Comment: I am creating the tasks in background and seems to be working when app is running in background and the device is not locked but somehow it doesn't seem to be working when device is sleeping/locked. Also I am not clear what exactly you mean by **none of your delegate methods will fire in the background unless you wrap them in a UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier assignment** as we need the delegate callbacks to start the background tasks, we can't create them on our own, can we?"

Comment: You should make a new question, with relevant code and I will see if I can make it more clear. Did you check out my TTLocationHandler project? You could drop it in your project and follow that example.

Comment: Yes I've checked your code and my code is almost similar to yours.. Anyways Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Add This Key to your Application Plist

```
Required background modes
```

Mark it as Array, and on its `item0` add this Value

```
App registers for location updates
```

The app will now get location data in Background too.