# Invoke get current coordinates every few seconds without NSTimer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, core-location

I know how to make this with NSTimer but I wan't to get current iPhone coordinates without timer on every few seconds. I can't use timer because I am getting coordinates while application is in background.
I have tried something but this calls every second not every 10 seconds as I wan't.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *loc = [locations objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDate* eventDate = loc.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (howRecent < 10)
    {
        CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];

        double lat = location.coordinate.latitude;
        double lng = location.coordinate.longitude;
        NSLog(@"lat:%f lng:%f", lat, lng);
```

First try to do background task every 10 seconds, but don't know where to set time if I do anything right here:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
            {
                [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
                backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        _pendingLocationsTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:_pendingLocationsTimerDuration
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(_acceptBestAvailableLocation:)
                                                       userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


        NSRunLoop *loop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [loop addTimer:_pendingLocationsTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [loop run];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
            {
                // if you don't call endBackgroundTask, the OS will exit your app.
                [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
                backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: The problem with relying only on a timer is that you are wasting resources while having no control or configurability. In my opinion, it is better to set up your location manger, with a controller class configured to broadcast and respond to the notification as applicable. See my edits and advice in answer.

Comment: Aren't you allocating `eventDate` and `howRecent` each time you get a callback...that would certainly lead to them getting reinstantiated inside every didUpdateLocations *callback*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had issues with timers in the background state. There is no guarantee that you will have an active run loop and so the timer will never fire until you come back to foreground. What I did is:

```
 NSRunLoop *loop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
 [loop addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
 [loop run];
```

I do this on a background thread inside BackgroundIdentifierTask begin and end calls. I am not fully confident that I have it all correct, in fact I looked at your question to see if an answer may help me confirm or correct my understanding of the requirements.

You also must have the background mode for location services enabled in your default info.pList if you want to continually monitor location. You do not need that if you are just using significantLocationUpdates or geofence.

My timer does work and does fire as intended set up this way. It did not work reliably prior to that.

Aside from that, you may be best off with no timer. Using your code above, just change the properties of your location manager. Desired accuracy and distance filter are properties that will reduce how often the manager sends out a new location notification.

See an example of my own location handler I just posted on github for anyone that is interested:

http://github.com/dsdavids/TTLocationHandler

I don't think the timer is the key. If you drop the TTLocationHandler class in your project, then take a look at how the LMViewController class responds to the handler.

```
NSNotificationCenter *defaultNotificatoinCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[defaultNotificatoinCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleLocationUpdate) name:LocationHandlerDidUpdateLocation object:nil];
```

sets up the controller as an observer. Whenever the handler determines a new or more accurate location has been received, handleLocationUpdate is called.

The locationManager, when startUpdating is invoked will send out new locations, many per second at first and when moving until the device is stationary and accuracy achieved. The *TTLocationHandler* is filtering these events and only sending notification as needed based on configuration.

Note that in -(id)init, _recencyThreshold is set to 60. So we are saving or displaying a pin every 60 seconds. If you want smaller interval, change this.

As it is, TTLocationHandler will always switch to significant location changes when in background unless the device is plugged in to power. You will not get that small an interval between updates if it is on battery power, but you will get updates.

I added a property to configure for continuous background updates without charging.

### Example Use of TTLocationHandler

I have added another class to the repository to show how I would go about achieving your goals with the my handler. I have added LMPinTracker class where you can add your code for storing and uploading the locations.

Look at LMAppDelegate.m

```
    self.pinTracker.uploadInterval = 30.00;
```

change that to whatever interval you want between uploads to the server.

```
    self.sharedLocationHandler.recencyThreshold = 5.0;
```

Change that 5.0 to the minimum time you want between stored locations. It won't be exact, will vary on the rate of travel and the signal strength but basically, after x seconds interval it will consider the stored location stale and attempt to get another accurate location.

Now look at the LMPinTracker.m file
Put your data storing code right after these two lines:

```
    // Store the location into your sqlite database here
    NSLog(@"Received location info: %@ \n Ready for store to database",lastKnowLocationInfo);
```

Put your web upload code right here after this comment:

```
    // Do your upload to web operations here
```

### Comments

This should do what you are looking to do, while still respecting user battery and background operation.

Basically, when a user is traveling, updates will be continuous at about the interval you have set.
When a user is stationary, there will be no updates and no significant activity.
When there is no new activity, you won't upload to web either.
Logging and updating resumes when user starts moving again.

If I were you, looking to refine it further, I would consider setting a region and time to check. If the user remains stationary for a length of time, switch to significantLocationUpdates only. Then you will power down the location services but be brought back up when the user gets underway once again.

Comment: Can you provide a little more code. This becomes nightmare how can I do any task on any ime interval when app is in background. Not only location I can't run any task in background...

Comment: @1110 see the link. You should see all you need in that repository. Feel free to use as you see fit.

Comment: I am trying to get from your code only what I need. And I just wan't to implement part (for the beginning) to do something every 10 seconds in background I will update my question with part of new code, I don't understand something ...

Comment: I think you may be on the wrong track with the timer. See my edit of my answer.

Comment: Give me a better idea of what you intend to do with the location when you receive it. I will show you how to modify the methods in LMViewController for your purposes.

Comment: Look at the github repository again. I have added the ability to update continuously even when unplugged. Note that this will impact the user's battery life considerably. You should consider if that is absolutely necessary for your purposes.

Comment: At the moment I don't care about battery. This is scenario that I need. When user starts the app I must get it's current location and store it in database (in iPhone). While user drives a car I need to store coordinates in that database and because I draw route that car pass I need to save coordinates all the time. The most important thing I need to invoke web service every X seconds to send all data to it. Now I did all this with timer and when app is active but I need to handle this even when app is in the background.

Comment: I will think this through and give my advice later today. When you save to database, is it a Core Data model?

Comment: No it's sqlite. So all i have to do is to get coordinates in background and every X seconds call web service.

Comment: Great, it works :) I just have one small question before close question. How can I pause this to stop getting coordinates? Because when I am in a room iPhone constantly try to find coordinates and it gets wrong coords (probably because it can't find it) and save it to db.

Comment: As it is set, the locationManager instance in TTLocactionHandler will stop sending updates once it has a location within the accuracy required if you are stationary. It will ignore events until you have moved about 10 meters. You can raise that default distanceFilter property, if you find it is responding unnecessarily. Another option, in PinTracker, you can check the location for distance from the previous. Skip the save, upload, proceses if it is outside the range you are interested in.

Comment: Another point. You can stop the continuous updates completely, anytime you deem it appropriate, by setting the continuesUpdatesOnBattery property to NO. If you set that to NO, it will switch to significantLocationChanges setting. In that case your app will be terminated but reactivated when the user leaves the area. You would need to work out when that is appropriate and when to go back to continuous updates based on your needs.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I am boring but now when I have this class in my project how to get current user location from any other class in application. Not last location just current? And I will not as anything more here :)

Comment: Not boring, I find I learn as much from helping as any other. You can ask the Location Handler for its currentLocation, that will likely be the same as the saved location in most cases. If you were not in Continuous mode I can see where that could be stale. I will look that over later. Busy now at my day job.

Comment: one more comment before moderators start to strongly suggest we go to chat. I added a class method and demo to make it easy to get the latest location directly from the handler instance. Send me a message if you want to discuss further options.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in background with a Timer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kAlertInterval target:self selector:@selector(checkLoc:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And in your method:

```
- (void)checkLoc:(NSTimer *)timer {
    //...get your location and...
     if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        //Do your background stuff
    }
}
```

I have this code working in some apps. Please, tell me if it works for you.

Comment: No NSTimer definitely doesn't work when app go's background mode. I just tried that.

Comment: Did you set the backgroundMode in the plist property? Set UIBackgroundModes with value location. I also suggest you to read this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4)