# Is there a way to set so that CLLocation do not update too often?

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

Obviously I need to update accurately. However not more often than once every 1 minute I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example use of CLLocationManager and a handler class to do what you are asking. Rather than a timer, it sets up a handler to respond to location events received, checks the accuracy and time passed since previous event, then sends out a notification based on your requirements.

The frequency of your response action is configurable as often as you require.

It works in the background, with battery saving configuration options.

See the code here [TTLocationHandler](https://github.com/dsdavids/TTLocationHandler)

You may also benefit from some of the discussion in this question thread [Invoke get current coordinates every few seconds without NSTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841017/invoke-get-current-coordinates-every-few-seconds-without-nstimer/12842463#12842463)

Comment: My purpose is to save user's battery. Obviously I prefer to get update as often as possible. So a handler that filter things won't help. Not really a big problem. Perhaps I should just ignore.

Comment: If the user has not moved, then I would ask if you need to keep confirming the location? The link shows how to use the location services to get updates as often as you wish, while not wasting resources when the device is stationary. If you do wish to get update every x seconds, no matter if user has moved or not then set the recencyThreshold to x, continuesUpdatingInBackgroundOnBattery to YES, and requiredAccuracy as applicable. This will trigger your response every x seconds at all times. It will try up to ten times to reach your accuracy requirement, then give best available.

Comment: I may have misread your comment. Basically the handler is doing as you say, ignoring unnecessary returns from the CLLocationManager instance. The advantage is the ability to configure which events to ignore and to start/stop the location services when possible, thereby saving battery.

Comment: +1 for you. Starting and stopping location service may save battery. Ignoring location service's notification won't right.

Comment: Also CLLocation service is running anyway if just one of the application use it. Am I correct here?

Comment: Ignoring the notification will be a waste of some battery, but may be necessary to allow time for the service to eventually give you the accuracy you require.

Comment: If you have other apps using location services, then they may cause the device to continue searching and reporting events. Each app needs to be responsible for itself and refrain from unnecessarily running the service when possible. Any time you can get by with only significant location change updates your app will have very little impact, or if region monitoring will suffice that is better still.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have position update you can:

1. Turn off updating
2. Start a timer for about 1 minute
3. Timer turns on updating

Done.